# Does Java EE run on Java SE's JRE?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

If I'm simply running a prebuilt Java EE (server) application, does it run on Java SE's JRE, the one found here?: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html

Comment: If you have a Java EE application you probably have a .war or a .ear file and it needs a Java EE application container. If you have a .jar you're probably not running a prebuilt Java EE application. Either way, everything runs under the Java JVM, which comes with Java SE.

Comment: No -- you will need to install a Java-based application server, something like Tomcat, JBoss or Glassfish

Comment: No, because EE is a super set of SE. You need an application server which supports Java EE and all the specifications.

Comment: Do the (third-party) containers implement the classes in the java ee specs (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/allclasses-noframe.html), or are the classes maintained by Oracle, like for Java SE?

Comment: It can run in Java SE environment if you use embedded container only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have asked two different questions:

> Does Java EE run on Java SE's JRE?

Assuming that you mean an implementation of the Java EE specifications (e.g. Glassfish, JBoss, Glassfish, WebSphere, etc), then the answer is **Yes**.

All of these will run on a Java SE JRE.  Indeed, you typically need to download a JRE separately from the Java EE implementation that you are using.

> If I'm simply running a prebuilt Java EE (server) application, does it run on Java SE's JRE?

The answer to that is **No**.  The web application needs a web container; e.g. Glassfish, JBoss, Glassfish, WebSphere, etc.

The webapp runs *in* a Java EE web container and the Java EE web container runs *on* a JRE.

---

Hopefully, the above will help you understand why the two questions you asked are different.

It should also be said that not all Java EE implementations are "equal".  Some of them (for example Tomcat) only implement a subset of the Java EE specifications.  However, a typical web application only requires a subset of Java EE; e.g. the Servlet, JSP and JSTL frameworks / implementations.

Answer (score 0):

The question is, why would you try to run a JavaEE application without J2EE-Server. 
If you want to do module tests, a subset of the functionality is sometimes enough to run limited parts of the application including h2-database access, message queuing in memory, asynchronous and timer-simulation, resource-injection ... together with a JUnit-Testrunner.

look for [ejb-cdi-unit](https://github.com/1and1/ejb-cdi-unit)